# SqlAlchemy, deep eagerloading after initial load

Tags: sqlalchemy, lazy-loading

Is it possible to initiate a deep eagerload after the initial object is loaded?

E.g., the following is great:

```
session.query(Foo).options(joinedload('bars.bazs')).all()
```

But, what if I already have `foo`?

```
foo = session.query(Foo).first()
if foo.something:
    do_nothing()
else:
    # <- would now like to eagerload 'bars.bazs'
    for bar in foo.bars:
        for baz in bar.bazs:
            # this is lazily loaded and slow
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you are already doing what you asked for in your first example.

```
session.query(Foo).options(joinedload('bars.bazs')).all()
```

This will only load the Foo objects to start with. Only when you access the Foo.bars attribute will it load all Bar objects AND all Baz objects for all Bar objects.

If you want to eagerload all Foo, Bar and Baz objects with the initial query you would have to specify it like this:

```
session.query(Foo).options(joinedload('bars'), joinedload('bars.bazs')).all()
```

or shorter:

```
session.query(Foo).options(joinedload_all('bars.bazs')).all()
```

Documentation in the last part of [this section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html#using-loader-strategies-lazy-loading-eager-loading).

To investigate how the objects get loaded from the DB when stepping through your code, you could pass `echo=True` to your `create_engine()` call.

Comment: Ah super, another careful reading of the docs you reference and the behaviour is clear.